# Time complexities of the given loops O(logn) or O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
//loop1
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i*=2) { }
//loop2
for (int i = 1; i <= logn; i++) { }
```

We argue with my friend about the loops that I think the first one is `O(logn)` and the latter is `O(n)`. However, for the latter one he says it is also `O(logn)` not `O(n)`.

Could you explain?

Comment: The first loop will iterate until infinity, since `i=0`.

Comment: it has been fixed

Comment: And given the second one is indeed that loop, he/she is correct, this will work in *O(log n)* as well.

Comment: **Why** do you think the latter is `O(n)`?

Comment: So both of them are logn in run time ???

Comment: @snr: well unless `logn` is something that does not scale with `log(n)`, this is a linear loop, but with `log(n)` as upperbound, so `log(n)` iterations.

Comment: But the upper limit *itself* is `log(n)`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem illimunating answer see it now, thanks sir

Answer (score 6):

Whenever in doubt, just substitute values of `n` with some values and dry run both loops.

Let's take `n = 100` for example.

> //loop1
>
> for (int i = 1; i <= n; i*=2) { }

Steps(in the form of `i,n`) are:

- 1 , 100
- 2 , 100
- 4 , 100
- 8 , 100
- 16 , 100
- 32 , 100
- 64 , 100
- <strike>128 , 100</strike>

Technically, it solves in `7` steps.

> //loop2
>
> for (int i = 1; i <= logn; i++) { }

- log<sub>2</sub>(100) = 6.64 ~ 7.
- Steps(in the form of `i,n`) are:

  - 1 , 7
  - 2 , 7
  - 3 , 7
  - 4 , 7
  - 5 , 7
  - 6 , 7
  - 7 , 7
  - <strike>8 , 7</strike>

This also gets solved in `7` steps. Hence, both approaches have same complexity which is O (log(n)).

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**

Both are `Log (n)` because, for an input *n*, both the loops will run for *Log (n)* times.

While the first loop runs *Log (n)* times because of `i *= 2` in the for-loop, the second loop runs *Log (n)* times because of the upper limit in the for-loop set directly to that value.

---

**Detailed:**

Big-O tells the **Rate of Growth** of a function. The second loop - which is the one you are confused about - is actually simpler of the two loops. You can see directly that for any input *n*, the function will always take time proportional to *Log (n)* only.

Hence the rate of growth of the second loop is proportional to *Log (n)* or in other words, equal to O(Log (n)).